# Using callbacks in Angular Subscribe?

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-observables

This is in my service file.
I can't change this function code, because its being used a lot of places in the app by other devs. HTTPclient is being used.

```js
getFieldDetailData(request?): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(this.apiBaseUrl + '/apiurl', { params: request })
            .catch(err => {
                err.statusmessage = 'fail';
                return err;
            });
    }
```

And in the same file I am writing this function to be used for callbacks.

```js
 testCallback(request, successFn, errorFn) {
        this.getFieldDetailData().
            subscribe(
                response => {
                    successFn(response);
                },
                error => {
                    errorFn();
                }
            );
    }
```

Now in my component file, I just want to pass the parameters and success and error methods in one line like this.

```js
this.service.testCallback.subscribe(this.request, this.success(r), this.error());
```

I want to do something with the response that comes back in my component with the parameter 'r'. I am new to observables so I believe I am doing something wrong here..

Comment: pass them like this `this.service.testCallback(this.request, this.success, this.error)`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the second function.  In your component, you can just call the first function and subscribe to it:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.yourService.getFieldDetailData().subscribe(response => {
        // do something here with the response.
        // error handling should be done in side the catch() operator
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This function that you implemented does not really extend existing functionality, Rxjs has already implemented these handlers for you.

```
testCallback(request, successFn, errorFn) {
        this.getFieldDetailData().
            subscribe(
                response => {
                    successFn(response);
                },
                error => {
                    errorFn();
                }
            );
    }
```

Imagine that we rewrote this function and it looks like this (we could just use the original getFieldDetailData function):

```
testCallback(request) {
        return this.getFieldDetailData(request);
    }
```

and now in your component you can just consume it as you wanted:

```
this.service.testCallback(request).subscribe(
    (r) => { // r will be the result of your request execution
        // your success callback code goes here
    }, 
    (error) => {
        // your exception handling goes here
    });
```

And of course you can do them one line if these callbacks are already implemented methods of your component.